# viewModel as viewModelExtended, cast?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I have problems with how to do this. I have two classes; `ProductViewModel` and `ProductExtendedViewModel`.

My scenario is basically that the `ProductExtendedViewModel` inherits the `ProductViewModel` and I want to cast `ProductViewModel` to `ProductExtendedViewModel`. How should I go about doing that?

This is what I have tried so far without success:

```
viewModelExtended = (ViewModelExtended) viewModel;
```

I get the tip that when casting a number the value must be a number less then infinity

I'm not that great at inherits and casting so this is all kinda new to me so please understand the kinda newbee question.

thanks

**EDIT**

```
public class ProductViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }
}

public class ProductExtendedViewModel : ProductViewModel
{
    public string ExtendedName { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Would it be possible to post details of both ViewModel and ViewModel extended - especially their definitions (i.e. the line that has "class ViewModelExtended...") and their properties? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly, in c# you can't cast from a Base Type to a Derived Type ("downcasting"), because you would be trying to generate information (i.e. what value should ExtendedName have?).

Your best bet would be to do this through composition - create a constructor on `ProductExtendedViewModel` that takes a `ProductViewModel`:

```
public class ProductExtendedViewModel : ProductViewModel
{
    public ProductExtendedViewModel()
    {
    }

    public ProductExtendedViewModel(ProductViewModel viewModel)
    {
        Name = viewModel.Name;
        Product = viewModel.Product;
    }

    public string ExtendedName { get; set; }
}
```

Which you could then call:

```
var productModel = new ProductViewModel {Name = product.Name, Product = product};

var derived = new ProductExtendedViewModel(productModel);
```

Note that you can still cast the Derived type back to it's base type, as this involves a loss of information:

```
var basetype = (ProductViewModel)derived;
```

I believe that the "Troubleshooting tip" of "When casting from a number [...]" is a red herring in this case, and is just a help around casting in general.

Answer (score 1):

As Zhaph says you can't downcast in C#. An alternative to his solution would be to use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) to create the instance of the inheriting class. This would look like this:

```
var productExtendedViewModel = Mapper.Map<ProductViewModel, ProductExtendedViewModel>(productViewModel);
```

See the documentation for how you can configure the mapping, but the basic mapping would be created like this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<ProductViewModel, ProductExtendedViewModel>();
```

AutoMapper is a good tool to handle all mappings between business objects and view models.